# Apache Camel: Problem with receiving GET response

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I have a server and client application that use Apache Camel to configure and manage their routing. I have a use case where the client makes a GET request to the server and the server should send back message data. The message data is defined by a generic class that can contain any Object instance. Currently, I'm generating either an array of chars or bytes of some random length for the message payload.

I'm having a problem with receiving the GET response on the client. Below are samples of the client and server consoles.

Client console:

```
2020-04-10 14:42:38.678  INFO 19968 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: rest-get started and consuming from: timer://http-get
2020-04-10 14:42:38.680  INFO 19968 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: rest-post started and consuming from: timer://http-post
2020-04-10 14:42:38.684  INFO 19968 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
2020-04-10 14:42:38.684  INFO 19968 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Apache Camel 3.1.0 (CamelContext: RESTClient) started in 1.715 seconds
...
2020-04-10 14:42:38.695  INFO 19968 --- [imer://http-get] rest-get                                 : start - rest-get
2020-04-10 14:42:38.701  INFO 19968 --- [           main] e.m.l.m.ApplicationMain                  : Started ApplicationMain in 5.176 seconds (JVM running for 7.624)
2020-04-10 14:42:39.021 ERROR 19968 --- [imer://http-get] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-489789-MITLL-1586544159020-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-489789-MITLL-1586544159020-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream cannot be cast to edu.mit.ll.mission_services.model.GenericMessage

Message History (complete message history is disabled)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[rest-get          ] [rest-get          ] [from[timer://http-get?delay=0&fixedRate=true&period=1000&repeatCount=1]       ] [       337]
    ...
[rest-get          ] [process1          ] [ref:process-get-response                                                      ] [         0]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream cannot be cast to edu.mit.ll.mission_services.model.GenericMessage
    at edu.mit.ll.mission_services.processor.GetResponseProcessor.process(GetResponseProcessor.java:18) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:64) ~[camel-support-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:396) [camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:153) [camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60) [camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147) [camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286) [camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:198) [camel-timer-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:78) [camel-timer-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [?:1.8.0_241]
...
2020-04-10 14:42:41.182  INFO 19968 --- [mer://http-post] rest-post                                : start - rest-post
2020-04-10 14:42:41.455  INFO 19968 --- [mer://http-post] e.m.l.m.s.DataProvider                   : produceCharArrayData: generated 15775578 characters
2020-04-10 14:42:41.455  INFO 19968 --- [mer://http-post] e.m.l.m.p.AddPostRequestBody             : adding POST request body:
GenericMessage [payload=[C@572d6e9b]
2020-04-10 14:42:43.497  INFO 19968 --- [mer://http-post] rest-post                                : end - rest-post
```

Server console:

```
2020-04-10 14:42:25.598  INFO 22860 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: get-data-by-size started and consuming from: jetty:http://localhost:9100/data
2020-04-10 14:42:25.599  INFO 22860 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: post-data started and consuming from: jetty:http://localhost:9100/post-data
2020-04-10 14:42:25.607  INFO 22860 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
2020-04-10 14:42:25.607  INFO 22860 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Apache Camel 3.1.0 (CamelContext: RESTServer) started in 0.342 seconds
...
2020-04-10 14:42:38.901  INFO 22860 --- [qtp913796146-39] get-data-by-size                         : start - get-data-by-size
2020-04-10 14:42:38.902  INFO 22860 --- [qtp913796146-39] e.m.l.m.s.DataProvider                   : getCharData: size=500
2020-04-10 14:42:38.905  INFO 22860 --- [qtp913796146-39] get-data-by-size                         : end - get-data-by-size
2020-04-10 14:42:43.097  INFO 22860 --- [qtp913796146-34] post-data                                : start - post-data
2020-04-10 14:42:43.100  WARN 22860 --- [qtp913796146-34] e.m.l.m.p.PostRequestProcessor           : process: null object
2020-04-10 14:42:43.100  INFO 22860 --- [qtp913796146-34] post-data                                : end - post-data
```

After some further reading and experimentation I think I found a solution.

The first thing I tried involved adding an `<unmarshal>` block before my processor as follows:

```
<route id="rest-get">
  <from
    uri="timer:{{http-client.timers.http-get.name}}?delay={{http-client.timers.http-get.start-delay}}&amp;fixedRate=true&amp;period={{http-client.timers.http-get.period}}&amp;repeatCount={{http-client.timers.http-get.repeat-count}}" />
  <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - rest-get" />
  <to uri="rest:get:{{http-client.endpoints.http-get}}" />
  <unmarshal>
    <json library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="edu.mit.ll.mission_services.model.GenericMessage" />
  </unmarshal>
  <process ref="process-get-response" />
  <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - rest-get" />
</route>
```

A slightly different way:

```
<dataFormats>
  <json id="jackson-format" library="Jackson"
    unmarshalTypeName="edu.mit.ll.mission_services.model.GenericMessage" />
</dataFormats>

<route id="rest-get">
  <from
    uri="timer:{{http-client.timers.http-get.name}}?delay={{http-client.timers.http-get.start-delay}}&amp;fixedRate=true&amp;period={{http-client.timers.http-get.period}}&amp;repeatCount={{http-client.timers.http-get.repeat-count}}" />
  <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - rest-get" />
  <to uri="rest:get:{{http-client.endpoints.http-get}}" />
  <unmarshal>
    <custom ref="jackson-format" />
  </unmarshal>
  <process ref="process-get-response" />
  <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - rest-get" />
</route>
```

Both of these work, but this seems like a problem (well, more of an annoyance) if I had a situation where I had dozens (or hundreds) of message type class definitions. Would this mean I would need to create a data format for every type? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: As plain JSON does not carry type information how would the unmarshaller know into what Java type you'd like to unmarshall a specific JSON object unless you tell it what the type is?

Comment: Fair point. I would assume then that if I don't have some set of Java classes representing message types, I could send different JSON messages (separate, unique JSON data structures), but then to use them in the Java application, would need to work with the JSON "object". Am I making sense?

Comment: You can unmarshall any JSON document into a list of maps. If that is what you mean?

Comment: I believe so. This removes the need for a bunch of Java classes (and how to convert back and forth), but leaves you with having to work the JSON "natively".